# is screen rotation don't stop auto-rotation with all ways in android?

Tags: android

I don't want to force the screen to be on landscape or portrait mode

I want the screen to still on its state and prevent rotating

I tried to put in the activity xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

then I added

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

and alos tried to put it:

```
android:screenOrientation="user"
```

then I tried this code :

```
setRequestedOrientation(getRequestedOrientation());
```

but it still rotate ?

Comment: android:screenOrientation="nosensor" works for me :S

Answer (score 1):

just try using

```
      android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

only

if you want to force the mode use this in the Manifest xml file

```
           <activity android:name="ABCActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
         </activity>
```

else just turn off your auto screen rotate on you android mobile :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample to change the Language in android, you can use this code to change the orientation too. From both Portrait and Landscape to just one of them(I assume that you know what is your current position).

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```